# Why my Controller setters aren't working in my PrimeFaces project?

Tags: java, controller, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I'm creating some pages with PrimeFaces 2.2.1 using the Showcase source-code as support.

I created a page exactly like [Spinner Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/spinner.jsf), with the same structure:

```
<h:form prependId="false">
    <p:panel header="Spinners">
        <h:panelGrid id="grid" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputLabel for="spinnerBasic" value="Basic Spinner: " />
            <p:spinner id="spinnerBasic" value="#{spinnerController.number1}" />

            <h:outputLabel for="spinnerStep" value="Step Factor: " />
            <p:spinner id="spinnerStep" value="#{spinnerController.number2}" stepFactor="0.25" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:panel>

    <p:commandButton value="Submit" update="display" oncomplete="dialog.show()" />

    <p:dialog header="Values" widgetVar="dialog">
        <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="2" cellpadding="5">
            <h:outputText value="Value 1: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{spinnerController.number1}" />

            <h:outputText value="Value 2: " />
            <h:outputText value="#{spinnerController.number2}" />
        </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Then I created my `SpinnerController` exactly like that one in the Showcase, only renaming the package to `org.myproject.view` (wich is the package name I'm using).

And added it to my `faces-config.xml`:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>spinnerController</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>org.myproject.view.SpinnerController</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

But when I click on the *Submit* button, the *Dialog* shows all values with `0`.

Using breakpoints, I can see that my `getNumber1` and `getNumber2` are running, but `setNumber1` and `setNumber2` never run. I can try to change the values using the spinners or directly typing the input field, the setters don't run as well.

Does anyone know what I'm missing in my project that exists on the Showcase project?

Comment: Are there any js errors in browser?

Comment: No Matt. And Firebug also show the values being posted correctly.

Comment: Ok, let's look further. The complete source code of the _SpinnerController.java_ can be found [here](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=de#q7ko4ejretI/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/java/org/primefaces/examples/view/SpinnerController.java&q=SpinnerController%20package:http://primefaces%5C.googlecode%5C.com&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc). Your facelet differs from the showcase facelet only in `<h:form prependId="false">`. Do you use `<h:head>` instead of `<head>`? As test you could try to update an outputText field on your main page (not on the dialog) and see if this works.

Comment: @Matt Handy, let's go: my *SpinnerController.java* is exactly that, only with another package name. Without `prependId="false"` the dialog don't show because the form ID is concatenated to the dialog ID. And yes, I'm using `<h:head>`. About the last test, none of my setters are being executed. But all getters works... I don't know what to look anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PrimeFaces really do heads burns sometimes.

Well, you helped me with my jQuery problem inside PrimeFaces. Now I think I can help you with your PrimeFaces problem:

- First, you don't need the `prependId="false"`. Your div can be "j_idt10:display" when is generated. You just need to put the "display" on the command button and JSF takes care about adding the first part (j_idt10).
- Second, avoid unnecessary ids. Your `h:panelGrid id="grid"` isn't called by any other control, so it don't need that id.

Here I just did these steps and the callback is ok.